# How to add data to jtable from different class?

Tags: java, io, jtable, package

I am working on  a GUI project based on groceryproducts. For the program, I have four window(the first one is main window, the second to add product to inventory and add the product in delimited text file, the third to remove product from inventory as well remove it from delimited text file and fourth to display products added to inventory from delimited text file).Now, I have finished making the three windows but I seem to been stuck when working on displaying products added to inventory. For viewing products I have a file in windows package containing all window classes for different windows in which viewGroceryProductInventory class has JTable added to it.

```
    package prog24178.javaassassins.project.window;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.table.*;
    import prog24178.javaassassins.guiproject.GroceryProduct;
    import prog24178.javaassassins.project.io.ViewProductsFromInventory;

  /**
    *
    * @author Bharat
    */
    public class ViewGroceryProductsWindow extends JPanel {

    //Create table with column names



                private String[] columnNames = {"Name of Product"
                                    ,"UPC Code","Price","Stock"
                                    ,"International","Department"};
                private Object[][] data = {};
                private DefaultTableModel tableModel = 
                               new DefaultTableModel(data,columnNames);
                private JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);



                public ViewGroceryProductsWindow(){
                JScrollPane jscroll = new JScrollPane(table);

                this.add(jscroll);


                tableModel.addRow(data);
         }

    }
```

I have another io package in which there are different classes to remove and add product to delimited text file. For ViewAGroceryProductInInventory class I have finished extracting the data from the file but now what should I do to add my fields into row in JTable which is defined in the windows class in window package? I know the data for row has to be in inserted into tableModel in order to display the row. Now, the problem I am facing is that I am doing this from another class in another package , so how I can add the fields from text file to the row data in the class in window package from the class in io package?

```
package prog24178.javaassassins.project.io;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import prog24178.javaassassins.guiproject.GroceryProduct;


/**
  *
  * @author Bharat
  */
 public class ViewProductsFromInventory{    


       Scanner input = null;  
       int counter = 0;

       public ViewProductsFromInventory(){

             File file = new File("GroceryProduct.txt");
             if(!file.exists()){
                    System.out.println("GroceryProduct.txt doesn't exist");
                    System.exit(0);
             }

             try{

                  input = new Scanner(file);
                  ArrayList<GroceryProduct> inventory = new ArrayList();
                  int counter=0;
                  while(input.hasNext()){

                       String record = input.next();      
                       String[] fields = record.split("\\|");

                       String nameOfProduct= fields[0];

                       String upcCodeOfProduct = fields[1];


                       double priceOfProduct = Double.parseDouble(fields[2]);
                       Boolean productInStock = Boolean.parseBoolean(fields[3]);
                       Boolean FromInternational = Boolean.parseBoolean(fields[4]);
                       String productDepartment = fields[5];                
                       GroceryProduct groceryProduct = 
                                      new GroceryProduct(nameOfProduct,
                                                        upcCodeOfProduct,priceOfProduct,
                                                         productInStock,
                                                       FromInternational,
                                                     productDepartment);


                       inventory.add(groceryProduct);

               }
                input.close();

               }catch(FileNotFoundException ex){

                System.out.print(ex.getLocalizedMessage());

             }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Column names and row data are part of the program's data *model*, so I'd give `ProductsFromInventory` a public `getModel()` method that returns a fully constructed `TableModel`, suitable for initializing your `JTable` *view*.

If you're allowed to define the format, you could supply the file name as a parameter to the constructor, and read the (delimited) names from the first line of the file.